# How to build the SQL query for given question?

Tags: sql

I have 2 SQL problems for which I need SQL query.

Table - Booking
[image]

Table - Adventure
[image]

Table - Tourist
[image]

Table - Location
[image]

Query1: Display **TourId**, **TourNa**me and **Email** of those tourist(s) who have booked all types of adventures. (Hint: Use the concept of Joins).

My Try:

```
Select DISTINCT T.TourId, T.TourName, T.Email 
From Tourist T 
INNER JOIN Booking B ON B.TourId = T.TourId 
INNER JOIN Location L ON L.LocId = B.Loc 
INNER JOIN Adventure A ON A.AdvId = L.AdvId 
    AND A.AdvType in (Select DISTINCT AdvType From Adventure)
```

Query2: For each booking, Identify the location whose bookingamount is greater than the *average* bookingamount of all the bookings done for that location. Display **LocId**, **LocName** and **Rating** for the identified location(s). (Hint: Use the concept of subqueries)

My Try:

```
Select B.Loc, L.LocName, L.Rating 
From Booking B 
INNER JOIN Location L ON B.Loc = L.LocId 
    AND BookingAmount > (Select AVG(B.BookingAmount) from Booking B Group By B.Loc)
```

Comment: Images of data are very bad on Stack Overflow. Some people won't see them, and it's harder for the people who can see them to use set up tests on dbfiddle or similar. In other words, you're much more likely to get a prompt and correct answer if you put your sample data as formatted text.

Comment: I removed the conflicting DBMS tags. Please add only one tag for the database product you are really using.

Answer (score 1):

Query 1:

```
select distinct tourid,tourname,email from tourist, booking, location
where 1=1
    and tourist.tourid = booking.tourid
    and booking.locid = location.locid
    and location.advid = adventure.advid
    and adventure.advtype = 'A'
```

Query 2:

```
select locid,locname,rating
from location
where locid in (select booking.locid from booking, (select 
b.bookid,b.loc,avg(b.bookingamount) as avg_ba from booking b group by 
b.bookid,b.loc) aa
where booking.bookid = aa.bookid and booking.loc = aa.loc and 
booking.bookingamount > aa.avg_ba)
```

Note: if it is a database design for any production server, I must say it needs to be changed ASAP.
Another Note: Please do not ever use pictures as references. It is very difficult to get information from pictures

Comment: These Both queries are not working.

For Query 1, AdvType is 'A', 'G', 'W' means A:Air, W:Water, G:Ground. So, Result should contain that result of those tourist(s) who book all type of adventures.

Query2 is resulting in No Data Available

Comment: Well, at least now you'll be able to get to the solution with these hints. And if you are looking for a prepared solution then my friend this is not the right platform I'm afraid. Good luck with your learning

Comment: No No. I am not asking for the complete solution. I just told you because Its not working. Btw, Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Query 1:-

```
Select DISTINCT T.TourId, T.TourName, T.Email 
From Tourist T 
INNER JOIN Booking B ON B.TourId = T.TourId 
INNER JOIN Location L ON L.LocId = B.Loc 
INNER JOIN Adventure A ON A.AdvId = L.AdvId 
    WHERE A.AdvType='A' AND A.AdvType='G' AND A.AdvType='W';
```

Query 2:-

```
Select B.Loc, L.LocName, L.Rating 
From Booking B 
INNER JOIN Location L ON B.Loc = L.LocId 
    WHERE B.BookingAmount > (Select AVG(B.BookingAmount) from Booking B Group By B.Loc);
```

Comment: Solution for Query 2: 
Select DISTINCT L.LocId, LocName, Rating From Location L INNER JOIN Booking B ON L.LocId = B.Loc Where BookingAmount > (Select AVG(BookingAmount) From Booking X Where X.Loc = B.Loc)

Your Query1 Resulting in No data Available and same with me.

Comment: Try this:- Select DISTINCT L.LocId, L.LocName, L.Rating From Location L INNER JOIN Booking B ON L.LocId = B.Loc Where B.BookingAmount > (Select AVG(BookingAmount) From Booking X Where X.Loc = B.Loc)